# How active is WPSE these days?

Tags: discussion

I've been wondering how active WPSE is now. Is it as active as this time last year, more active, or less active?

Is there any way for me to find out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Answers by month plot](https://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/1019930/answers-by-month#graph) is trending down (ignore the last data point, which comes from a partial month).

To remove seasonal effects, one can compare the same periods of 2018 and 2019 years. 
There were 9681 answers posted in the first eight months of 2018, and 8807 answers in the same period of 2019. That is, [year-over-year growth](https://www.thebalance.com/year-over-year-yoy-growth-calculation-definition-3305970) is -9%.

All these numbers include deleted posts as well, to isolate trends in post creation from trends in deletion.

Comment: That's fairly depressing. If that were a stock chart, I'd consider a long-ish term short sell.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been getting into all of the dev communities in an effort to expand my networking & opportunity reach, so I had the same question, but in my present experience I'd say it can only be projected to get more popular within this next year as it's about to be open season for the tech jobs that need to be filled & the growing amount of money hungry jr devs looking to find quick fixes. That's just my personal opinion however